# Select two variables from in a single MYSQL request

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to extract two variables from the same MySQL request depending on the value of a variable. I can extract these variables in two separate queries, but I'm sure it must be possible to combine them to produce two /columns of data in a single statement, perhaps with an if statement?

I have a JOIN statement in there which is sort of throwing me a bit.

The first request:

```
SELECT variables.value as "Mean Power"
FROM variables
INNER JOIN stat_types ON variables.id=stat_types.id
WHERE stat_types.name="Mean";
```

The second request:

```
SELECT variables.value as "Maximum Power"
FROM variables
INNER JOIN stat_types ON variables.id=stat_types.id
WHERE stat_types.name="Max";
```

The only thing which has changed is that the stat_type name changes from Max to Mean, and I would like to change the output column name accordingly.

There will always be the same number of results for these two requests.
Any help you can offer would be great!

**Edit:**
I should make it clear  that I am after two time series' , not individual maximum values. The closest I have now achieved is with the code suggested below, slightly edited as follows:

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    (CASE WHEN st.name = 'Mean' THEN v.value END) AS `Mean Power`,
    (CASE WHEN st.name = 'Max'  THEN v.value END) AS `Maximum Power`
FROM variables v
INNER JOIN stat_types st
    ON v.id = st.id
WHERE
    st.name = IN ('Mean', 'Max')
```

Which gives:

```
|id|Mean Power| Maximum Power|
|1 |NULL      |9010          |
|1 |NULL      |8999          |
|1 |NULL      |9011          |
|2 |9053      |NULL          |
|2 |9040      |NULL          |
|2 |9045      |NULL          |
```

Great. However, I want this:

```
|Mean Power| Maximum Power|
|9053      |9010          |
|9040      |8999          |
|9045      |9011          |
```

So I need to combine the power values and I don't need the id as an output. For each value I also have a timestep which could be used if necessary. There is a max and mean for every timestep (same number of values)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN st.name = 'Mean' THEN v.value END) AS `Mean Power`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN st.name = 'Max'  THEN v.value END) AS `Maximum Power`
FROM variables v
INNER JOIN stat_types st
    ON v.id = st.id
WHERE
    st.name = IN ('Mean', 'Max')
GROUP BY
    v.id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I have tried implementing this, but I have an issue: I do not want just a max value but the whole time series - so I removed the MAX command. I also removed the GROUP BY command for the same reason. Doing this produces the3 columns (id, mean pwr, max, pwr) - great! However, the data is not arranged concurrently as I would like. I want all the concurrent (related to the same timestep) max and mean power values to be on a single row, instead, I have all the max values with mean set to null, then the inverse for the mean values. Any ideas? Some sort of UNION?

Comment: Removing `MAX` and `GROUP BY` completely changes my answer to...something else.  At this point, you should add sample input data to your question and also show us the exact output you expect.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried to put a bit more detail in my question in an Edit. What do you think?

Comment: Doesn't help.  You showed the _output_ from my answer along with what you want to see.  You need to sample _starting_ data, with the expected output.

Comment: Thanks Tim. In the end I worked it out by just combining the two select queries with an inner join on the date.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem here is just about combining two select queries and producing two columns of "concurrent" data. The key to solve it was knowing that each of the values I would like to output have a date associated, so in the end it was just a case of doing a join of the two select queries based on the date:

```
SELECT Max as "Max Power", Mean as "Mean Power" FROM 

(SELECT variables.date as "date", variables.value as "Mean Power"
FROM variables
INNER JOIN stat_types ON variables.id=stat_types.id
WHERE stat_types.name="Mean") as Mean

INNER JOIN

(SELECT variables.date as "date", variables.value as "Max Power"
FROM variables
INNER JOIN stat_types ON variables.id=stat_types.id
WHERE stat_types.name="Max") as Max

ON Max.date=Mean.date
```

thank you for your input